# Dropping the secondary y-axis in combined barplots in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am combining two bar graphs using R that have the same Y-axes so I want to drop the second one as in B:

[image]

I found a way to do so using ggplot2 but just wondering if its possible within the barplot feature.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is possible but requires quite a bit of fussing.  See the help for `layout` and `par`.  You could also just combine the data used to construct the two plots and create a single barchart from the combined dataset.  The help for `barplot` will be useful, especially concerning the `space` and `names.arg` arguments.

Comment: Thanks whuber for placing the question here, I am a slow learner and just got the difference between stackexchange and stackeoverflow. I read the ?barplot description but didn't find anything useful about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`barplot` does this right out of the box.  To illustrate, let's create the data represented by the two plots:

```
a <- c(2,4,6,8,9)
b <- c(5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9)
```

Here is the color vector to parallel `c(a,b)`:

```
col <- unlist(mapply(rep, c("#fb0019", "#8767fc"), c(2,3, 1,4)))
```

In this environment, just one function call does it all:

```
barplot(cbind(a, b), beside=TRUE, space=c(0.2, 1.2), names.arg=c("", ""), col=col)
```

[image: Figure]

This method passes the two vectors of data as *columns of a matrix* (*via* `cbind(a, b)`), causing it to produce two groups of bars.  The values of `space` give, respectively, the relative spacing between within-group bars and between the groups.  Finally, `names.arg` suppresses the automatic group labels that would be posted and `col=col` determines the colors of the bars from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

To make both graphs stand closer to each other, like in your example, you need to meddle with par() a bit and I'm not sure which arguments do you need to mess with.

If you just need to get rid of the axis you can use `axes=F` inside the barplot function. Just be sure to specify the y axis range so you know both graphs are using the same scale.

```
a=c(1,2,3)
b=c(2,3,4)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

barplot(a,ylim=c(0,5))
barplot(b,ylim=c(0,5),,axes=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Fino! This does help to remove the second Y-axis which is an important knowledge, but does so at the cost of leaving some space in between. I can adjust this manually using a picture editor, but for efficacy's sake I wanted to complete the whole process within R. Please let me know if you have a workaround.